# What's wrong with this mongoose query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```js
    const images = await tbl
      .find({
        creator_id: req.user._id,
      })
      .select({
        creator_id: 0,
      })
      .then((images) =>
        images.forEach((image) => {
          image.file_name = process.env.IMAGE_HOST_URL + image.file_name;
        })
      );
```

It fails in the .`then` bit. Not sure why.

Comment: What errors are you getting? You could share some logs

Comment: Actually, it's not throwing an error, but it's returning an empty array. That's not expected. Without the `.then` bit the list is not empty.

Comment: You are using `await` and `then`. Use one or another.

Comment: AH, I think I know why. remove the await on the first line. or break out the .then to happen after on it's own. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue happens because your promise is already resolved before you call .then. remove the await or break out the .then to stay on its own

```
   const images = tbl
  .find({
    creator_id: req.user._id,
  })
  .select({
    creator_id: 0,
  })
  .then((images) =>
    images.forEach((image) => {
      image.file_name = process.env.IMAGE_HOST_URL + image.file_name;
    })
  );
```